# Paypal API. Cant recieve payer information from PDT

Tags: php, paypal

Having problems receiving information about payer in the "thank you" page (return URL).

I'm using code from [GitHub](https://github.com/paypal/pdt-code-samples/blob/master/paypal_pdt.php) and here is code:

```
$pp_hostname = "www.paypal.com"; // Change to www.sandbox.paypal.com to test against sandbox
// read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
$req = 'cmd=_notify-synch';

$tx_token = $_GET['tx'];
$auth_token = "###################";
$req .= "&tx=$tx_token&at=$auth_token";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://$pp_hostname/cgi-bin/webscr");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
//set cacert.pem verisign certificate path in curl using 'CURLOPT_CAINFO' field here,
//if your server does not bundled with default verisign certificates.
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Host: $pp_hostname"));
$res = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
if(!$res){
    //HTTP ERROR
}else{
     // parse the data
    $lines = explode("\n", $res);
    $keyarray = array();
    if (strcmp ($lines[0], "SUCCESS") == 0) {
        for ($i=1; $i<count($lines);$i++){
        list($key,$val) = explode("=", $lines[$i]);
        $keyarray[urldecode($key)] = urldecode($val);
    }
    // check the payment_status is Completed
    // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
    // check that receiver_email is your Primary PayPal email
    // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
    // process payment

    $email = $keyarray['payer_email'];
    }
    else if (strcmp ($lines[0], "FAIL") == 0) {
        // log for manual investigation
    }
}
```

And I getting the empty `$email` variable. When I use it in the sandbox changing the host URL to www.sandbox.paypal.com and using sandbox account it's all ok, after a user pays I'm getting the payer email. But in real www.paypal.com it's not working.

Comment: What is the content of $res when testing in real Paypal ?

Comment: It was empty. I fixed this problem by adding `'User-Agent: company-name'` here `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Host: $pp_hostname", 'User-Agent: company-name'));`